# Syntax highlighting error in syncolor.vim with VIM 8.0 on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim, vi

I recently installed VIM 8.0 on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine. When I open vim, it outputs an error:

```
> vim ~/.vimrc
Error detected while processing /usr/local/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syncolor.vim:
line   36:
E254: Cannot allocate color Orange1
E254: Cannot allocate color Orange1
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

When I hit enter, it opens without syntax highlighting (but with a colorscheme, the colors change slightly if I change :colorscheme to something different).

But if I run as root, it opens with syntax highlighting.

```
sudo vim ~/.vimrc
```

I assumed it was a permission issue, so I set syncolor.vim to be readable by all:

```
> ll /usr/local/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syncolor.vim 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4.0K Dec 22 23:29 /usr/local/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syncolor.vim
```

Still no luck. Then I wondered if vim was set to something different under root than under my user:

```
> which vim
/usr/local/bin/vim
> /usr/local/bin/vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Dec 22 2016 23:01:25)


> sudo which vim
/usr/local/bin/vim
> sudo /usr/local/bin/vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Dec 22 2016 23:01:25)
```

My next thought was that root's TERM was different:

```
> echo $TERM
xterm-256color
> sudo echo $TERM
xterm-256color
```

I'm at a loss. What else could be different between my user and root that would cause colors not to load?

Update: Under both root and my own user:

```
:echo $MYVIMRC
/home/aaron/.vimrc
```

Comment: Does your and root's `.vimrc` file differ in any way? What if you start Vim with `vim -u /dev/null` and then manually go through the options in your `.vimrc` file one by one until you find the offending one? Also, I'm assuming `vi` and `vim` are the same executable, because you do say you ran `sudo vi`, not `sudo vim `...

Comment: Yes, vi and vim are the same. I ran it as vim just to be sure. When I run :echo $MYVIMRC, it returns /home/aaron/.vimrc in both cases